# AJAX fade on submit

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a quick question about this fade out div. I use facebox, and after the submit, and it shows an error it'll show this:

http://puu.sh/1uPnF

however I want that to fade away, after they've caught that message. On my AJAX handler for the submit form, this is the PHP code:

```
<?php
require_once('....');

$form_name = $_GET['form_name'];
$form_comment = $_GET['form_comment'];
$date = date('Y-n-j');
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];


 if($form_name == '') {
    echo("<div class='alert alert-error-x'>Don't forget to enter a name, as we need to identify who's commenting on this article!</div>");

} else if($form_comment == '') {
    echo("<div class='alert alert-error-x'>Please do not leave the comment field blank, we want to know what you're saying!</div>");

} else {
mysql_query("INSERT INTO comment (id, articleid, name, comment, date, ip) VALUES (NULL,'{$_GET['id']}','{$form_name}','{$form_comment}','{$date}','{$ip}')");

    // output comment
    echo "<div class='alert alert-success-x'>Posted by <strong>$form_name</strong> on     <strong>{$date}</strong>$form_comment</div>";
}

?>
```

This is where the output of what would be submitted, on the article.php:

```
 <?php

$amount_get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comment WHERE articleid='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']) . "'"); $comments = mysql_num_rows($amount_get);

$grab = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comment WHERE articleid='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']) . "'");

if (mysql_num_rows($grab)==0) {

    echo "<div class='alert alert-note-x'>Sorry, it looks like their are no comments to be displayed, check back later!</div>";
}

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($grab)){

    ?>

 <div id="new_comment"></div>
 <div class="article-comment">
 Posted by <b><?php echo $row['name'] ?></b> on <b><?php echo $row['date'] ?></b>  
 <br />  
 <?php echo $row['comment'] ?>
 </div>
   <?php } ?>         
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I tried adding the below code in the core.js file, which is located on my site at krissales.com

```
$(window).bind("load", function() { 
$('#new_comment').fadeOut(4000);
});
```

However it did not work. If you want to test the demo, then check it out at: http://www.krissales.com/#/media/30.This-is-a-new-article-for-Testing!

What is it that I'm doing wrong, please?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you including two jQuery libraries? 1.4.4 and 1.4.2?

Comment: Also, why are you using 3 different functions to run code onload? You're using `$(window).bind("load", function () {});`, `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {});`, and `$(init);`

Comment: Finally, the problem is that you're attempting to fade out `#new_comment` on page load. But you can't comment until after the DOM is ready. So when do you actually want fade out the comment? Just call the code to fade it out when you want...don't just put things in `document.ready`

Comment: And if you want to use HTML5 features, such as `<header>`, `<footer>`, etc., you probably want to use the HTML5 doctype - `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Answer (score 1):

If you're using AJAX, I suggest you use jquery's `ajax` method (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to make the call to your PHP file.

Then, use the `success` callback function of that method to show the correct response.
Hiding the response can then simply be done by fading out the div (with a delay if you want that).

```
if ($('#new_comment').length > 0)
{
    $('#new_comment').delay(4000).fadeOut();
}
```

You are now trying to fade out the message on window load, but since you're using AJAX, there is no page reload happening.

Hope this helps you!